# How to check if a user already likes a blog post or not in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to set my like unlike button by verifying a query that the user already likes this post or not. If the user already likes this, the button will be "Unlike" and "Like"  otherwise. I can not find the proper way to make the query and how to implement it in my template. Thanks in advance.

My model:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tweeter = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='user_tweets')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

class Like(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='liked_user')
    liked_tweet = models.ForeignKey('Tweet', related_name='liked_post')
    liked_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s liked %s tweet' % (self.liker, self.liked_tweet)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply query `Like` model with the `Tweet` and `UserProfile` instance for which you are verifying. If a record exists then user has already liked that tweet.

Sample:

```
is_liked = False
try:
    Like.objects.get(liked_tweet=tweet, liker=user)
    is_liked = True
except Like.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Comment: ``is_liked = Like.objects.filter(liked_tweet=tweet, liker=user).exists()`` seems to be more readable.

Comment: @ErnestTen agreed.

Comment: that's fine but how can I use this data in my template to change my like button. for example I want to apply like this:

    {% if is_liked %}
    <button>Unlike<button>
    {% else %}
     <button>Like<button>
    {% endif }

Or anyhow I just want this thing to be happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for the record with `user` and `tweet` in `Like` table.

```
like_obj, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(liker=user, liked_tweet=tweet)
if created:
   # code for new user liked tweet
else:
   # code for record found with user and tweet so unlike tweet by like_obj.delete()
```

Comment: that's fine but how can I use this data in my template to change my like button. for example I want to apply like this: {% if is_liked %} <button>Unlike<button> {% else %} <button>Like<button> {% endif } Or anyhow I just want this thing to be happen. Thanks.